# SQL How to query a has_many_through relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, has-many-through

I have three models that have a has_many_through relationship like this:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_workspaces
  has_many :workspaces, through: :tag_workspaces, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_workspaces
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_workspaces, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class TagWorkspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :workspace
end
```

I need to write a query using sql language to get all the tags that belong to a specific workspace.
So far my query looks like this:

```
select '0' as "value", 'Seleziona un Tag' as "name"
union all
SELECT name AS "value",
       name
FROM tags
```

But I need to select only the tags that belong to workspace 1, for example. How could I accomplish that? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, this would be ...

```
select t.*
from   tags t
join   tag_workspaces tw on tw.tag_id = t.id
join   workspaces w on w.id = tw.workspace_id
where  w.id = 1
```